# .htaccess edit middle of URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, web-deployment

I'm trying to change a specific section of a URL, rewriting the request via .htaccess commands. I just want to change one specific part of it, but the value of that part can vary. The initial URL would be something like:

http://www.domain.website.com/hello/search

Given this, how would I replace hello, knowing it won't always be hello. I've been using htacces.madewithlove.be in order to test my solutions but I've only found things that can append to the end of replace the entire thing

I should also clarify that this is specifically going to have to be in the `RewriteCond RewriteRule` format. So an expression that would replace the whole thing would be like the following:

```
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) ^example(A-Za-z0-9\.]*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-website.com/$1
```

and the result would be http://www.new-website.com/

Answer (score 1):

Considering the word you want to replace is the first word after origin, you can use this

```
(https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/)[^\/]+(\/.*)?
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/vJGaDy/2/)

Comment: @Maria-Andersado yeah, this covers the case you specified in update, if you need specific origin to change than you can replace `(https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/)` this part with `(your desired domain)`

Comment: When I enter the following in htacces.madewithlove.com, the result is that everything between the $ and ? are appended to the input URL: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example([A-Za-z0-9\.]*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \/\/[^\/]+\/)[^\/]+(\/.*)?

Comment: @Maria-Andersado i don't have much experience with `.htaccess`, but try this `RewriteRule ^[^\/]+\/(.*)$ https://www.askapache.com/someword/$1 [R=301,L]`  this seems to give what you're looking for